# system of differential inequalities: where do these inequalities come from

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

**Lemma.**  Assume $0 < r < 1 < p$ and $k,λ ≥ 0$. Let the functions $y,z ∈
C^1(0,T)$ satisfy $y ≥ 0$, $z > 0$ and the system of differential inequalities $$z'\geq y^p$$

$$y'+\lambda y +kz'^r \geq z $$
on $(0,T)$. Then $T < ∞$ ($T$ is the maximum lifetime of the solution).

I'm having difficulty understanding two inequalities that he does at the beginning of the demonstration, below I transcribe the beginning of the test.

**proof.** By translating the origin of time, we may assume that actually $y, z ∈ C^1([0,T))$ and $z(0) > 0$. Fix $γ$ such that $\max(r,1/p) < γ < 1$. It follows from the
first inequality of system that, for all $ε > 0$, there exists a constant $C_ε > 0$ such
that
$C_ε{z'}^γ ≥y^{pγ} +(3λ+1)y−ε$ and $C_ε{z′}^γ ≥3k{z′}^r −ε$,

I want to understand how this constant can exist in this way, it seems that the author uses derivative continuity to write these inequalities, but it is strange to me to be able to include this term (3λ+1)y in the inequality, since $\lambda$ is already pre-defined .